# UItableView is not refreshing data after loading for second time the View

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, viewdidload

I'm having some trouble with a UITableView. It loads perfectly the first time I open it, but after the second try its not getting into the viewDidLoad method which causes the data not be refreshed on my tableview. I also made the proper release on my dealloc method. Any ideas about this? I've looked thru google but I didnt get anything useful. Thanks a lot for all the help you can provide me!

Here are my viewDidLoad and viewDidUnload methods

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
 {
[super viewDidLoad];
saved_news.rowHeight =85;
addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Edit" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(edititems:)];
[self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:addButton];
[self setSaved:[CoreData sharedInstance].selectItems];
[saved_news reloadData];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{

[super viewDidUnload];
saved = nil;
saved_news = nil;
addButton =nil;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`viewDidLoad` and `viewDidUnload` are typically called only once during the lifetime of a controller (unless there's a low memory situation). I think what you are looking to use here are the `viewDidAppear:` and `viewDidDisappear:` methods.

Comment: Great! You can also use `viewWillAppear:` instead of `viewDidAppear:`; this will refresh the table view just before it appears.

Answer (score 0):

Call

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated;

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated;
```

as you require load table here
[Yourtablename reloaddata];

Hope this helps..